# Property refresh does not exist on type NextRouter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

Have the following code:

```
"use client";

import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function CreatePrompt() {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
  const [content, setContent] = useState("");

  const router = useRouter();

  const createPrompt = async (e: any) => {
    await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8090/api/collections/prompts/records", {
      method: "POST",

      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },

      body: JSON.stringify({
        title,
        content,
      }),
    });

    setContent("");
    setTitle("");

    router.replace(router.asPath);
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={createPrompt}>
      <h3>Create a new Prompt</h3>

      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Title"
        value={title}
        onChange={(e) => setTitle(e.target.value)}
      />

      <textarea
        placeholder="Content"
        value={content}
        onChange={(e) => setContent(e.target.value)}
      />

      <button type="submit"> Save prompt</button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

Getting the following error:

```
Property 'refresh' does not exist on type 'NextRouter'
```

On the line:

```js
router.refresh()
```

Answer (score 2):

The `refresh` method does not exist on [`useRouter`](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/functions/use-router#routerprefetch) return when imported from `next/router`. It exists on [`useRouter`](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-router) return when imported from `next/navigation`, which you should be doing since you seem to be using the [`app`](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/project-structure) router (directory):

```js
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation';
```

Answer (score 1):

To use ,

```
const router = useRouter();
router.referesh();
```

Instead of importing useRouter from "next/router" import it from "next/navigation"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).